# USB: error 0x000007d1

Tags: windows-8, usb, android

Is there any way to fix error 0x000007di? It occurs when I plug in phone USB. 
I'm using Windows 8.

What I want to do is to root my Android phone when I connect it. It feels like everything's fine and I can browse files, images and whatever is stored on the phone, but when I try to root using VROOT, I wait for it to detect the phone connected, and Oops! error 0x000007d1, I googled and found that it's a USB driver problem. I updated drivers, but I'm still getting the same problem. I tried another way to root without using the VROOT application, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: 0x000007d1 = ERROR_BAD_DRIVER (The specified driver is invalid.) Which drivers do you have installed?

Comment: Samsung galaxy USB driver

Comment: look if there are updated drivers.

Comment: I have the latest updates.

Comment: try different versions of your ROOT tool.